# is possible to remove a column from a ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

i would like to know if is possible to remove a column from a ResultSet object, i know simply as don't select it into the select statement would be good enough, the thing is i have a huge ResultSet that has 2 columns with over 300k records, i just require the 2 column for the first step of my program, the second step takes the ResultSet as it is and print it on a Excel file using POI. The only thing that comes to mi mind is just not to display it when printing it, but that will cause me to modify the second step logic.

Then i wonder if is possible to do something similar to delete a row to delete a column.

```
resultSet.getAbsolte(4);
resultSet.deleteRow();
```

Thanks

Comment: I hope you know that [`deleteRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#deleteRow--) deletes that row from the database, not just from the result set.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, i wasn't aware of that, i thought this method only affects the ResultSet content. Good thing is i didn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read out both columns into some data structure:

```
class TableX {
   List<?> firstColVals;
   List<?> secondColVals;
}
```

Then, after you done with first step, which needs values from both columns, simply do

```
TableX tableVals = readTable(); // your usual while (rs.next()) { ... }
firstStep(tableVals);
tableVals.secondColVals = null; // now unneeded data can be freed by GC
secondStep(tableVals.firstColVals);
```

Comment: Victor thanks, this is a nice workaround, do you know if there a way to populate a ResultSet with the content of a data structure, so  TableVals.firstColVals could be ResultSet type instead of List<?> ?, the second step receives a ResultSet as parameter.

Comment: Never did it myself, but try this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html. I assume, you may remove unwanted data on 2nd step by doing cachedRowSet.updateXXX(2, null);

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best approach, by updating all the rows and set all the seconds column to null, that way the program prints nothing on the second column, i had to change the ResultSet to ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE to be able to update the records. thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @Israelm Then you are updating the underlying database as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oracle tutorial is vague on this, but it seems you need to explicitly call `cachedRS.acceptChanges()` to update underlying DB. I'd still would prefer above solution w/o `cachedRS` for clarity.

Comment: @VictorSorokin True, but the comments by israelm seemed to indicate he was calling it on the resultset.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Yes you're right, by setting the CONCUR_UPDATABLE i was updating the underlying database as well which is wrong. I am sticking to the method Victor Sorokin suggested chachedRowSet.update() to avoid any data lose. Thanks for your comments guys.